# How to use Dictionary to provide data (which are defined in runtime) to DataGrid (xaml) in SL4

Tags: xaml, datagrid, silverlight-4.0, runtime

I am looking for information on how to provide data to DataGrid using Dictionary. My use case is: I have WebService that provides me a table with the content (and column names) I get know in runtime.

My current implementation of a data tuple is:

```
 public class GridTuple : Dictionary<string, string>
    {

    public GridTuple(IDictionary<string, string> cv, int id) : base(cv)
    {               
        TupleId = id;
    }

    public int TupleId { set; get; }

    public override string ToString()
    {

        string result = TupleId + " ";
        for (int i = 0; i < ColumnNames.Names.Count; i++)
        {
            result += ColumnNames.Names[i] + " " + this[ColumnNames.Names[i]] + " ";
        }
        return result;

    }
}
```

...and implementation for DataGrid in xaml is:

```
<sdk:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" HeadersVisibility="All" x:Name="dataGrid"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"                          

                    ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfGridTuples}" MouseLeftButtonUp="dataGrid_MouseLeftButtonUp" 
                          SelectionMode="Single" Grid.Column="1" >

                <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                       <!-- ValueForColumn1 is a key in my GridTuple -->
                    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding [ValueForColumn1]}" />
                </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>

 </sdk:DataGrid>
```

...

Comment: Solved. I have found this post - http://blog.bodurov.com/How-to-Bind-Silverlight-DataGrid-From-IEnumerable-of-IDictionary/. I have created Columns with Bindings following this post. Only change I made was to put a ids of columns in Bindngs in '[' ']' because SL4 provides support for bindings of dictionaries in xaml: new DataGridTextColumn
                        {
                            Header = "ID",
                            Binding = new Binding("[ID]")
                        });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I have found this post - http://blog.bodurov.com/How-to-Bind-Silverlight-DataGrid-From-IEnumerable-of-IDictionary/. I have created Columns with Bindings following this post. Only change I made was to put a ids of columns in Bindngs in '[' ']' because SL4 provides support for dictionaries in xaml: new DataGridTextColumn { Header = "ID", Binding = new Binding("[ID]") });